# Multiple Views bound to a single element in backbone.js

Tags: backbone.js

I am trying to bind two click events to a single HTML element in two different views. One of the views triggers the event, the other does not.

One of the view has body as its **el** attribute. If I change this view's **el** to the same element as the other view's, then both events get triggered.

Is this expected? How can I bind click events for the same element in two different views?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is expected.  Backbone uses [jQuery delegates](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) for the event binding.  Which means, the event is actually bound to the view's EL, not directly to the child node.

When you say, "the same element", do you mean literally the exact same node in the DOM?  Or, do you mean a node with the same selector?  I guess I'm not entirely clear.

Answer (score 0):

can i ask why you want to have 2 views binding to the same element?

from my point of view, you should only have 1 view that represents the element itself
and event's bound to an element should be defined in that view only.

you will run into trouble when you are binding click events to elements that don't belong to the view

if you bind trough the [`delegateEvents`](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#View-delegateEvents) hash, these events are contained within the `el` of the view. 
if you are however defining the click yourself, your code becomes less managable.

so, on to what you can do:

[events!](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Events)

you can define 1 view, holding your button and trigger an event when the button is clicked, while other views that need to handle some code when that button is pressed don't bind directly to the button click itself, they can listen to that raised event.

example on jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/saelfaer/Qck5w/2/

the gist of it in code here:

```
// an event aggregator object to trigger and bind to
var events = _.extend({}, Backbone.Events),

// two views that talk to each other trough the event aggregator
var myButtonView = Backbone.View.extend({
    // first view binds a click event to the button
    events: {
        "click a" : "myClickEvent"
    },
    initialize: function(){
        _.bindAll(this, "render");
        this.render();
    },
    render: function(){
        return this;
    },
    // click event executes this function, which triggers a custom event on the events object.
    myClickEvent: function(e){
        $(e.target).blur();
        events.trigger("sidebar:myCustomClickEvent");
        return false;
    }
});

var myPanelView = Backbone.View.extend({
    // second view binds to that event, and executes the custom click handler
    initialize: function(){
        _.bindAll(this, "render", "myClickEventHandler");
        events.bind("sidebar:myCustomClickEvent", this.myClickEventHandler);
        this.render();
    },
    render: function(){
        return this;
    },
    // the click handler does some logic (appends div) when the event is raised.
    myClickEventHandler: function(){
        var txt = $('<div/>').text("you just clicked the button. (bound in other view)");
        $(this.el).append(txt);
    }
});
```